# This program is showing compile time error.. illegal start of type for (Integer it : arr), why it showing error?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
class Test
{
    Set<Integer> st = new HashSet<Integer>();

    Integer arr[]={1,1,2,2,4,8};

    for (Integer it : arr)
    {
        st.add(it);
        System.out.println(st);
    }

    public static void main(String ar[]){

        System.out.println("Main");


}}
```

Comment: The for loop isn't inside a block (a method, a constructor, an initialiser).

Comment: you have to write your code always inside methods.not just inside class u can declare variable inside class but you have to write your codes inside methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your for-loop inside the main method, like this:

```
public static void main(String ar[]) {

    Set<Integer> st = new HashSet<Integer>();

    Integer arr[]={1,1,2,2,4,8};

    for (Integer it : arr) {
        st.add(it);
        System.out.println(st);
    }


}
```